# Telerik RadGrid fix the font size when exporting to Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, telerik-grid, export-to-word

I've a [Telerik RadGrid](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/overview) with 11 columns that is getting displayed normally on the web application,
however when I try to export this grid to word, it doesn't fit the document width and shows only the very first 6 columns,

I'm using `_grid.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();` to export to Word
And I've tried to tweak its size a bit using `_grid.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Parse("300mm");` but still some columns are still not visible,

from the Word itself, I've tried to reduce the font size to 10 on the exported document, and I found that this will help displaying the entire grid on one document, however i cannot set set the Font property of the MasterTableView as it has no setter,

is there a way to make sure the entire grid columns will be displayed.

The exported document with hidden columns image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I've used

```
_grid.MasterTableView.Style["font-size"] = "10px";
```